# less does not show expected output after sourcing a script in .cshrc

Tags: csh

In our university we have a script to setup the working environment under linux. Since I am lazy I decided to add this process to the shell initialization by adding `source /setup/script` to `.cshrc`. However since I have done so, I can't use less anymore. When I run `less somefile`, the output of said script is displayed by less **instead** of the contents of `somefile`.

I managed to work around the issue by using `source /setup/script > /dev/null`

So the questions:

1. Is it wrong/is there a better way, then adding `source initscript` to `.cshrc`
2. How can I continue using `less` (without the output redirect, the script echos some ussage information I find helpfull)?
3. Why is this happening?

**edit**: OK since I feel uncomfortable adding the scripts, here is a minimal example that breaks less for me:

`.cshrc`:

```
source ~/test
```

`~/test`:

```
echo "test"
```

If I now do `less test` I get `test` instead of `echo "test"`, by the way the output is the same for other files, I checked. The output is within the less environment (pressing <kbd>q</kbd> returns me to the console)

*update*: There is an additional annoying thing:
`less imaginaryPathToNonexistingFile`- works, same output. less has some sort of memory: every time I change the file I open the display of `test` is one line down on the screen, until it is right over the `filename(END)`at the bottom of the console

*update*: I found that there is an environment variable called `LESSOPEN` set to `|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s` (thx vonbrand)

```
#!/bin/sh -
#
# To use this filter with less, define LESSOPEN:
# export LESSOPEN="|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s"

lesspipe() {
  case "$1" in
  *.[1-9n]|*.man|*.[1-9n].bz2|*.man.bz2|*.[1-9].gz|*.[1-9]x.gz|*.[1-9].man.gz)
    case "$1" in
        *.gz)   DECOMPRESSOR="gunzip -c" ;;
        *.bz2)  DECOMPRESSOR="bunzip2 -c" ;;
        *)  DECOMPRESSOR="cat" ;;
    esac
    if $DECOMPRESSOR -- "$1" | file - | grep -q troff; then
        if echo "$1" | grep -q ^/; then #absolute path
            man -- "$1" | cat -s
        else
            man -- "./$1" | cat -s
        fi
    else
        $DECOMPRESSOR -- "$1"
    fi ;;
  *.tar) tar tvvf "$1" ;;
  *.tgz|*.tar.gz|*.tar.[zZ]) tar tzvvf "$1" ;;
  *.tar.bz2|*.tbz2) bzip2 -dc -- "$1" | tar tvvf - ;;
  *.[zZ]|*.gz) gzip -dc -- "$1" ;;
  *.bz2) bzip2 -dc -- "$1" ;;
  *.zip) zipinfo -- "$1" ;;
  *.rpm) rpm -qpivl --changelog -- "$1" ;;
  *.cpi|*.cpio) cpio -itv < "$1" ;;
  *.gif|*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.pcd|*.png|*.tga|*.tiff|*.tif)
   if [ -x "`which identify`" ]; then
     identify "$1"
   else
     echo "No identify available"
     echo "Install ImageMagick to browse images"
   fi ;;
  *)
    case "$1" in
        *.gz)   DECOMPRESSOR="gunzip -c" ;;
        *.bz2)  DECOMPRESSOR="bunzip2 -c" ;;
    esac
    if [ ! -z $DECOMPRESSOR ] ; then
        $DECOMPRESSOR -- "$1" ;
    fi
  esac
}

if [ -d "$1" ] ; then
    /bin/ls -alF -- "$1"
else
    lesspipe "$1" 2> /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: We can't know unless you show us the contents of the script.

Comment: I can't imagine how they manage to do that, I'd be very interested ;-)

Comment: @terdon: I added a min example, it is running under Redhat if that helps

Comment: @vonbrand: From the fact, that the pros here think that it is actually related to script, and what I have found, I am afraid I have to disappoint you: either I have an old/broken/... version of less, or there is some bigger thing besides less doing the breaking

Comment: I can't see anything that might have such a bizarre efect there. Anything in `~/.lessrc`, any alias for less, setting any variable named `LESS<something>` somewhere?

Comment: @vonbrand: not that I can see, I have no `~/.lessrc`. A lookarround in the enviornemntvariables yielded this: `LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s`, I put this up top.

Comment: However I don't see why my `souricng`triggers this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is addressed on this FAQ page for the less command (see section ["Why are there problems if my .cshrc, .profile or ENV files produce output?"](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html)):

> If you use the LESSOPEN feature, having your shell produce output can
>   cause other problems. Since less uses the shell to invoke the LESSOPEN
>   filter, the output from the shell will appear at the beginning of the
>   output from the filter program, causing it to appear to be part of the
>   file.

Comment: Welcome to *nix.SE. Please paste the most relevant/important information from links in-line (e.g., in a quote block), to avoid link-rot.

Comment: I have to accept this awnser unchecked since I no longer work on the relevant system or have access to it. I took the freedom to quote the link. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tyler on why this is happening.

To answer your other two questions:

> 1. Is it wrong/is there a better way, then adding source initscript to .cshrc
> 2. How can I continue using less (without the output redirect, the script echos some ussage information I find helpfull)?

You most likely want to move the `source /setup/script` to your `.login`, as per the *Startup and shutdown* section of `man tcsh`:

> Non-login shells read only /etc/csh.cshrc and ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc on startup.
>
> ...
>
> Commands  like  stty(1)  and  tset(1),  which  need be run only once per login, usually go in one’s
>          ~/.login file.

`less` invokes the shell, but it's a non-login shell, and therefore does not produce any output from `.login`.

The caveat here is that something like `screen` won't execute the `~/.login` file.  That may or may not be important to you.